# Find replacement decorative wood spindle for screen door

Tags: doors

I have a wood screen door in the screened-in porch that is missing a decorative spindle. It came with the house, so I don't know the manufacturer. There are also no marking anywhere on it, and I've asked a few contractors about suggestions to no avail. I have yet to see any doors at the box scores, along with a local Harvey Industries store, and it seems modern doors are either fiberglass or metal. The door is fine and I'd like to find a replacement spindle or have one made, but I'm not sure where to look. I lack the woodworking skills and tools to "clone" myself, so I was asking here for suggestions.

[image]

Link to album with images of the door:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/veosm.jpg

Comment: Rather than replacing a single spindle, I'd find something similar and replace them all. That way you don't have to perfectly replicate the pattern. By finding something off the shelf, you'll save a lot of money over having a custom made part, and the effort to replace 8 isn't much more than to replace a single one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A local wood working shop with a lathe can replicate one of those, if you get them a template and you let them know the size of the pin on ONE end.

Comment: I know there is no way to tell, but do you have an estimate on what this might cost or should cost? I had called a local place and was quoted $50 (I got the impression they didn't want small jobs).

Comment: Small jobs cost as much to set up as large ones for the most part, if you turn one or twenty, the cost goes down per piece the more are ordered. Sounds reasonable for a custom turned piece. Will either of the other 2 examples work? there was never a dimension given between the 2 horizontals. There are some that may be 6 inches over all but the part you see may only be 5 to 5 1/2", the 2 examples are dead ringers for what you have in the picture, just all depends on the length between the horizontals....  get back to me, see if it can get done, if so mounting instructions are needed too, later-

Comment: It is 8 inches between the two slats. I figured that a 7.5 inch (without tenon) this would do it and it's on the way (comes in a day): http://www.rockler.com/7-1-2-decorator-spindle . I will let everyone know how it goes.

Answer (score 2):

If they are about 6 inches long, how about one of [these](http://www.craftparts.com/534-wood-birch-spindles-p-1142.html)

[image: spindle]

If it's not quite right, you can search the web for *decorative spindles* and find either one that matches or a full set of similar spindles and replace them all. This may still be chaper than having one custom made by a wood shop.

Comment: Ah! I kept searching for "dowel" and had no clue about a spindle. Thanks a ton for this. This looks like my best route before having to have something done custom.

Answer (score 0):

That's actually a pretty common shape design you would probably not have as much problem finding as you might think if you have an architectural salvage type place nearby. They were mass produced and I see them often when I'm out at those type places. Some quick scouring on the web at places like ebay would probably also turn something up or possibly even at a local hardware store in the right section. Here's an example (not an endorsement, just an example) http://www.ebay.com/itm/Lot-of-15-Architectural-Salvage-Wood-Spindles-8-1-2-/151206600920?pt=LH_DefaultDomain_0&hash=item23349da0d8

Answer (score 0):

A possible lowcost alternative might be your local vocational school. If you know any highschool age kids in your neighborhood they might be able to get you the contacts you need. In my area the typical cost is the cost of materials.